# undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass with random date

Tags: ruby, datetime, random

I use this code to generate date:

```
DateTime.strptime("10/26/2015 07:09:52 AM", '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

But when I use this code to generate random date:

```
(Time.now - rand(15552000)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

I get error:

```
undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass
```

Can you give some solution how I can fix this?

Comment: Strange, I could not reproduce the error you are reporting. in `irb` I get `=> "09/13/2016 07:17:14 AM"
`

Comment: How is the first line related to the question?

Comment: You get the error somewhere else.

Comment: Looks like I have nil somewhere.